# Saving state of expanded child rows in datatable after reload div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

My application is working with database and when data in DB changes, my page is reloading. To show data I used bootstrap datatable. My datatable always has one child, hidden column and I want to save expanded state before refreshing page. I did it but I have 2 problems:

1. When I am expanding rows after reload, child rows has also expanded icon like parent-rows
2. expanded-row icon doesn't change

Here is a example what I want and what I get.

[image]

I was trying dynamically change tr class but it didn't work or just I was making it wrong.

My js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshtable() {
       var openRows = [];
       var table = $('#table').DataTable();
       table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
          var tr = rowIdx;
          var row = table.row(tr);
          if (row.child.isShown()) {
             openRows.push(rowIdx);
          }
       })    

       $('#tablediv').hide();
       $('#load').show();
       $("#tablediv").load("mainrf.jsp");


       setTimeout(function(){
          var table = $('#table').DataTable();      
          var arrayLength = openRows.length;
          var roww;
          for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
              roww = table.row(openRows[i]);
              roww.child(format(roww.data())).show();
          }     
       }, 500);
    }


    function format(value) {
       var temprow = value.toString();
       var pieces = temprow.split(/[\s,]+/);
       var piece = pieces[pieces.length-1];
       return '<table><tbody><tr><td>Comments:  ' + piece + '</td></tr><tbody></table>';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, by changing for loop. Now I am just triggering expand button click.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            $( 'td:first-child', table.row( openRows[i]).node() ).trigger( 'click' );
        }
```